# Why is my app not in the store when I search it?

Tags: google-chrome, store

I made a app for the chrome store and when I search it, It shows no results? I paid the developer and it seems to not be worth it if people just cant find it on the store.

P.S. If I click the app from the developer dashboard, I shows the store page.

Comment: Might help if you said which app it was, when you submitted it to the store, and if it was approved...

Comment: Here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/milana-website/egdglnbiibimdjejdfmbfknniphkbinf

Comment: How long does it take to get approval and how do you know?

Comment: Comes up when I search for "Milana"...

Comment: Same for me, I can see it in search

Answer (score 0):

The app showed up in a search for 'Milana Website'. Could it be that you just had to wait for Google to process the submission?

Comment: I published it like an hour ago. And its just a teacher tool so its not spam.

Comment: has google approved it? or do the not have to... i'm not an android developer

Comment: I do not know. Its my first app and I published it. Is it named what i named it in the json file or is is something else?

Comment: try searching the name of the main file (aka the title of the app)

Comment: Heres the link but now try searching it in the store. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/milana-website/egdglnbiibimdjejdfmbfknniphkbinf

Comment: cool app, anyways maybe there's a setting that disables it from being searched. FYI i'm using google chrome if that helps...